# Timezone in datetime string

Tags: python, utc

I have the following string in an XML file:

```
<Platform FeedLastUpdated="2017-03-29 19:37:05">StackOverflow</Platform>
```

What is the best way to convey that it is in UTC tz? For example:

```
"2017-03-29 19:37:05 UTC"
```

Is there a standard way that we should use?

Comment: Is your question about the most appropriate time format? I am assuming you saw this already: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is already quite close to ISO 8601 and its cousin [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339); by using `T` instead of   as separator, you're there. ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 specify the timezone offset (or `Z` for UTC), like this:

```
2017-03-29T19:37:05+00:00 # UTC
2017-03-29T19:37:05-05:00 # New York time
2017-03-29T19:37:05Z      # Shortcut for UTC
```